# Adding or removing items in fragment based on input data given by other fragment of same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two fragments in one activity. Based on the flag, which is based on input data entered in fragment1 I should add an item or should not add an item in the second fragment. My problem is condition satisfies for the first time if I go back to the first fragment and change input data. It is not reflected in the second fragment.

Comment: can  you update some code fragments you use?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

Using FragmentPagerAdapter you can show and hide.
initially ,

```
boolean tabUpdate = false;
```

Set as flag based item count updated function on adapter

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
            if (tabUpdate){
                return noOfFragments;
            } else {
                return noOfFragments - 1;
            }
  }
```

Getting changes based on first fragment, need to update adapter and set view pager on next fragment

```
    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // updated the adapter 
    mTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager); 
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem("fragment to set on next view");
```

Add or remove both function need to update the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the flag in the activity that is hosting both fragments, so when the value is changed from one it should reflect in the other one:

So in the  MainActivity:

```
private bool flag = false;
```

In the fragment use something like this:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).flag = true
```

And in the second fragment

```
if ( ((MainActivity)getActivity()).flag ){
// DO SMETHING
}
```

I have an app with the same approach and it works fine.